# Unity UI positioning not in correct spot when set by a script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a little project on Unity and I want a random spawn position for buttons in the UI. So I did this script:

```
Animator anim;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    transform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
    randomspawn();
    
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Touch");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

private void randomspawn()
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-125,125), Random.Range(-150, 150));
}
```

But the button seems to be attached to the bottom left corner. There is nothing here, no anchor, no item nothing

See image (the button is the white circle):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUUE1.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Canvas is in `Screenspace Overlay` mode. I such case the coordinates are in **screen pixel space**!

For the UI `0,0` is the bottom-left corner. Your passed values are just way to small -> very close to the bottom-left corner.

You could use e.g.

```
private void randomspawn()
{
    transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(0,Screen.width), Random.Range(0, Screen.height);
}
```

to place it anywhere on the screen.